# Bernoulli and flight

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation, lift

Am not a physicist but Bernoulli's principle states that when fluids flow faster lower pressure is created, thus explaining lower pressure on the top of a plane wing... But in the case where the air is not moving but the wing is passing through the air, the air particles do not move faster they only move up and down, getting out of the way of the wing as it passes. clearly airplanes fly but what is the correct application of Bernoulli

Comment: What matters is that the plane and the air move relative to each other.

Comment: Yes I know that.. but I thought that the low pressure was due to faster flowing fluid... In the airplane wing situation the air is not moving so why is there lower pressure generated

Answer (score 0):

You should read John Denker's excellent [online account](https://www.av8n.com/how/htm/airfoils.html) which explain everything in a down-to-earth but thoroughly corrrect manner, and with the minimal amount of mathematics.

Comment: Thanks... Will do